# Calculation of locus , If sum of of the perpendicular distances of a variable point $P(h,k)$ from lines $x+y-5=0$ and $3x-2y+7=0$ is always $10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If sum of of the perpendicular distances of a variable point $P(h,k)$ from lines $x+y-5=0$ and
>
> $3x-2y+7=0$ is always $10.$ Then How can we prove that $P$ must be move on a line.

$\bf{My\; Trial}::$ Let $PA$ be perpendicular distance of line $x+y-5=0$ from $A$

and $PB$ be the perpendicular distance of line $3x-2y+7=0$ from $B$.

Then given $PA+PB = 10$.

So here $\displaystyle PA = \left|\frac{h+k-5}{\sqrt{2}}\right|$  and $\displaystyle PB = \left|\frac{3h-2k+7}{\sqrt{13}}\right|$

So We get $\displaystyle \left|\frac{h+k-5}{\sqrt{2}}\right|+\left|\frac{3h-2k+7}{\sqrt{13}}\right|=10$

Now I did not understand how can we simplify to get an equation of line

Help me please, Thanks

Comment: Thanks G-man. but i have a doubt when we take aal 4 cases and drawing into a paper we get a quadrilateral. but here we have to prove that locus is line.

Comment: I don't think the answer (the final locus) is a line... It's the union of 4 *line segments*; together they form a quadrilateral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two intersecting lines divide the entire plane in four regions. Each of these regions is determined by a set of inequalities, such as:
$$(R_1) \quad \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} x+y-5 & >&  0 \\ 3x-2y+7 &>&0\end{array}\right.$$
In this region, $|h+k-5|=h+k-5$ and $|3h-2k+7|=3h-2k+7$, so
$$\frac{\left| h+k-5 \right|}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\left|3h-2k+7\right|}{\sqrt{13}}=10$$
becomes
$$\frac{h+k-5}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3h-2k+7}{\sqrt{13}}=10$$
You can simplify this, but it is clearly the equation of a line. Keep in mind that this part of the locus is only valid in the region described by $(R_1)$: so you only draw a part of the line given by this equation. It will be the lige segment joining the two initially given lines, in region $(R_1)$.

You can do the same for the other three regions, such as
$$(R_2) \quad \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} x+y-5 & < &  0 \\ 3x-2y+7 &>&0\end{array}\right.$$
in which case everything remains the same except that now $|h+k-5|=-h-k+5$. And so on for $(R_3)$ and $(R_4)$.

You'll end up with four line segments, joining the two initially given lines in the four different regions.

A simple check: where the line segments meet (one of) the other two lines, the distance to one of the lines is (obviously) 0, so this should happen at a distance of exactly 10 to the other line. This should help to determine the four corners of the quadrilateral that will be formed, making it easy to draw the complete locus.

Comment: Thanks StackTD but i have a doubt that why we will take only one region. why we will not take all 4 region.

Comment: I explained it in more detail for one of the four regions, but you have (indeed) 4 cases/regions in total. If you carefully read the last paragraph, you may figure out the result without having to do a lot of calculations.

Comment: To StackTD I have a doubt, Can we say that the locus of above question is a Quadrilateral.Thanks

Comment: Yes. Have you tried drawing the solution?